# Efficient complex operations on every combination of columns between two matrices (R)

Tags: r, vectorization, outer-join

Given two matrices, I want to perform a complex operation between values in every combination of columns (specifically, I wish to calculate the sum of the square root of the product of the values in two given columns).

This sounded like a job for `outer`:

```
set.seed(123)
a <- matrix(abs(rnorm(12)),nrow=4)
a
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.56047565 0.1292877 0.6868529
[2,] 0.23017749 1.7150650 0.4456620
[3,] 1.55870831 0.4609162 1.2240818
[4,] 0.07050839 1.2650612 0.3598138

b <- matrix(abs(rnorm(12)),nrow=4)
b
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.4007715 0.4978505 1.0678237
[2,] 0.1106827 1.9666172 0.2179749
[3,] 0.5558411 0.7013559 1.0260044
[4,] 1.7869131 0.4727914 0.7288912

m <- outer (
  as.data.frame(a),
  as.data.frame(b),
  Vectorize(function (x, y)   sum(sqrt(x*y),na.rm=T))
)
m
         V1       V2       V3
V1 1.919315 2.429191 2.488925
V2 2.672994 3.432185 2.630920
V3 2.373466 2.859966 2.800881
```

... but this is proving to be prohibitively slow for the size of the matrices I'm working with. What's the fastest way to do this? I don't think this approach is appropriately taking advantage of vectorization.

P.S. the `as.data.frame` call is a further aspect of this approach I don't like, but I don't get the desired output without it. Instead, `outer` returns an array of:

```
dim(m)
[1] 4 3 4 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sqrt each of a and b and then use crossprod giving the result shown which is the same as m.  (Note that the question used random numbers without set.seed so m here is different than in the question.)

```
crossprod(sqrt(a), sqrt(b))
##          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
## [1,] 1.940283 1.957321 1.914920
## [2,] 2.740899 2.611588 2.564304
## [3,] 2.983868 2.957246 2.872090

m
##          V1       V2       V3
## V1 1.940283 1.957321 1.914920
## V2 2.740899 2.611588 2.564304
## V3 2.983868 2.957246 2.872090
```